# QT - 3rd Party Callback Not Calling back?

Tags: c++, qt, stdcall

I've created a test application for a 3rd party lib I am using, it compiles fine but never seems to hit __stdCall WriteDone.

from the example code it looks like this function

```
    if(cmcd->BuildISOImage(isoName, &CMCDBurner::WriteDone, NULL) == TRUE)
    {
        qDebug() << "inside build iso";
    }
```

Calls this code, but to the best of my knowledge it never makes it here.

```
void __stdcall CMCDBurner::WriteDone(int DeviceId, bool Failed, void *arg)
{
    qDebug() << "inside write done.";
}
```

This is the whole test application

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "MCDBcls.h"
#
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    char* cdDestination = "\\";
    char* isoName = "C:\\LinearSystems\\AVCommand\\ISO\\aviso.iso";

    CMCDBurner* cmcd = new CMCDBurner();

    cmcd->ClearAll();

    cmcd->InsertFile(cdDestination, "C:\\DLS\\Interviews\\Test_001\\20130515-87701\\interview.xml" );
    int c = cmcd->Prepare();
    int b = cmcd->GetFilesCount();

    if(cmcd->BuildISOImage(isoName, &CMCDBurner::WriteDone, NULL) == TRUE)
    {
        qDebug() << "inside build iso";
    }

    return a.exec();
}


void __stdcall CMCDBurner::WriteDone(int DeviceId, bool Failed, void *arg)
{
    qDebug() << "inside write done.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized you try defining the WriteDone function for the class `CMDCDBurner`. 
Try moving the function in front of your main method and leaving out the `CMDCDBurner::`:

```
void __stdcall WriteDone(int DeviceId, bool Failed, void *arg)
{
    qDebug() << "inside write done.";
}
```

Comment: thanks, when i tried it produces the error: C2761: 'void CMCDBurner::WriteDone(int,bool,void *)' : member function redeclaration not allowed

Comment: it didn't work out but I contacted the vendor and they are looking into it, it seems to stem from their compatability w/ VS2010 compiler as the above code works in 2008, I appreciate the help!